# Is there any method in HibernateTemplate like queryForObject in Jdbctemplate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is there any possibility that can i use `HibernateTemplate` and `Jdbctemplate` in single program?

I am using `HibernateTemplate` to store and retrieve the data, but when it comes to check username and password I am unable to check it.

```
private JdbcTemplate template;
int i= template.queryForObject(
    "select count(*) from login where username=? and password=?", Integer.class, s1);
```

Comment: HibernateTemplate has been deprecated several years ago. You should use native Hibernate code instead. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate

Comment: Chances are high, you need the full row anyhow for later work (e.g. for access to other user data) so why not just fetch the object and see if you get something back.